# WCF RIA Services link dropdownlist not present in project properties (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, wcf

I committed a project to VSTF and then pulled it down locally on another machine. It works fine on my dev box, but on the other machine, the WCF RIA Service link appears to be gone and there is no option to re-add it in the project properties.

See image for clarification:

[image: http://imgur.com/XIwfB.png]

What's missing on the other machine?

Answer (score 1):

Hope WCF RIA Services for Silverlight 4 is installed?